# How to pass parameter middleware laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have read many ideas about how to pass parameter in middleware but if there is any possibilities to get full example about that

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to customise the middleware functionality.

Check out this post by Matt Stauffer (if you have not read).

It clearly answers your question. It would get you started.

[Passing parameters to middleware](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/passing-parameters-to-middleware-in-laravel-5.1)

In Laravel API I'm not sure if there is a hasRole() method. But we can create one likewise.

**Extending the laravel *Auth* class with hasRole()**

Two tables are needed Users & Roles.

Add this in ***user model***:

```
public function hasRole($role) {
    return Role::where(array('user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'role' => $role))->get();
}
```

Remember to include the ***Role model*** path on top.

Add this inside the ***Middleware***:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role) {

    If($this->auth->guest()) {
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }

    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasRole($role)) {
        return $next($request);
    } 
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: if hasRole() comes with laravel or I should make it in User model?

Comment: I mean is hasRole() comes with laravel ?

Comment: @allaghi check the updated answer. I hope I   have answered your question correctly.

Comment: ArtisanBay,  could I know the fields of role table ?

Comment: By default 4 fields... id(PK), name(admin, manager, user, ..), created_at, updated_at. Fields can grow depending on application need.

Comment: I am sorry but what about user_id filed , ? I have issue with it

Comment: I did eloquent relationship between user model and role model, but I still have issue with user_id in where condition ?

Comment: User table fields are ( id, name, email, password..etc + role_id)

Comment: Try toIn the where condition for user_I'd pass Auth::user()->id

Comment: I did some changes and it looks like work fine.
in User model  I did this function ....

public function hasRole($role) {
        return $user = User::where('email',Auth::user()->email)->whereHas('role', function ($query) use ($role) {
            $query->where(['role_name'=>$role]);
        })->first();

    }

Comment: In where condition you could match role_id, since it is the primary key of that table and also its best practice.. Rest all looks spot on :) Happy that you were able to fine the solution. You could mark this resolved if you are through.